# Adiabatic expansion and first law

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, adiabatic

So I wanted to know whether the following equation would be correct for an adiabatic process.

**adiabatic expansion **
∆U = -W

**Adiabatic compression**
∆U = W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Delta U$ is the change in internal energy of a system.

In an adiabatic expansion the change in internal energy is negative ie the system does work on the surroundings and the change in internal energy is positive when the system is compressed ie the surroundings do work no the system or put another way, the system does negative work on surroundings.

Let us assume that $W$ is the work done **by** the system on the surroundings and so this $W$ is positive when the system does work on the surroundings and $W$ is a negative quantity when the surroundings do work on the system.

The first equation you give is $\Delta U = - W$ is the correct one if you define $W$ to be the work done **by** the system on the surroundings..

If the system expands $\Delta U$ is negative and the work done by the systen $W$ is positive so applying the equation

$$\Delta U = - W \Rightarrow {\rm negative} \,[\Delta U] = - ({\rm positive} \, [W])$$ so you have negatives on both sides of the equation.

Now consider an adiabatic compression  where $\Delta U$ is positive and the work done by the system $W$ is negative.

$$\Delta U = - W \Rightarrow {\rm positive} \,[\Delta U] = - ({\rm negative} \, [W]) \Rightarrow \rm positive = positive  $$ so you have positives on both sides of the equation.

If you tried to use $\Delta U = W$ for the compression you would have a positive on the left hand side and a negative on the right hand side.

---

There is another convention used where $W$ is the work done **on** the system by the surroundings then the equation you would use for an adiabatic change would be $\Delta U = W$.
Try it and see that the sign are the same on both sides of the equation.

Comment: thank you so much . I understand now because my text was using the other convention and it had me eternally confused. I will use the normal one where work done on system is positive since I'm accustomed to that :)

Comment: Okay I have one more question. for the adiabatic expansion using the convention opposite to mine , won't the negative signs cancel out and give me ∆U=  W which isn't the same as using the other convention where ∆U = -W

Comment: @user122343 Which is the convention opposite to yours? Write the equation in symbols and define clearly what $W$ is.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases  ∆U = -W. 
Work done by the system is considered positive.

Comment: How can that ever be ? If the gas is expanding isn't work being done by gas hence it's negative ?